# How to set hyperlink dynamically from inputted text in angular2 and make it clickable with url?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular component,

```
  <div contentEditable="true"  id="mytext" ></div>
  <button type="button" (click)="goSee()">SEE ME !</button>
```

In class,there is goSee() method because I want to change selected text(later url) to a real clickable href.

```
goSee()
     {
  var startIndex = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
  var endIndex = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset;
  var slicedText = document.getElementById("mytext").innerText.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
   document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML.anchor(slicedText);

    }
```

Entering url to "mytext" and selectedText works,,But **NO** hyperlink and clickable link appears .... Please Suggest me and Thank you all in advance..

Comment: `document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML.anchor(slicedText);` ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to use `link` method to create anchor with the `href` attribute. Second, `innerHTML` is a property and you have to set it. Assuming that `slicedText` is a url you want to put into `href` attribute, you can achieve what you're trying to do like this:

```
var existingLinkText = document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = existingLinkText.link(slicedText);
```

Also, if your template is part of the component's template, I would suggest to use [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) to get access to the DOM instead of global `document`.

Comment: It works and display likes a hyperlink !! But when slicedText is url like 'www.google.com' ,it goes 'www.google.com' from my prj like 'localhost:8080/Prj/www.google.com' ..Doesnt go just 'www.google.com' !

Comment: this is a different question. you need to have a `href` starting with `http://` for you browser to treat it like a link to a different resoure, rather than a relative link. you can mark this answer as accepted if it answers your question and ask another question for specific details of your second question. put a link to the other question here.

Comment: but before read [this](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/2545680)

Comment: Thank you Maximus .. I realize more of href .. : )